# Login failed for user 'test'

Tags: sql-server, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to use bellow method to initialize my database which is hosted on one of Microsoft Azure's servers.

```
  WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection","UserPacient", "PacientID", "PacientUsername", true);
```

The connection string looks like this

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=***********" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I ran the application it throws

> Login failed for user 'HelpMed'.

Any idea on why this error??

I need to specify that from SSMS I can connect and access the database from Azure...

Comment: Can you connect via SSMS if you use the same connection string, verbatim from your web.config? I don't know if that's what you meant that you did or not.

Comment: Yes, I can connect using the same connection string..

Comment: I solved the problem by assigning the user to a login that has the needed rights to access the database

Comment: "Password=sa123" not * sign use in webconfig file

Comment: I added the * sign to hide the password, thanks